# Telerik Date Picker in IE <8

Tags: telerik, datepicker, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, html

I'm using the Date Picker from the Telerik MVC library.  It appears and works fine in Firefox and IE8+ in standards mode.

[image: Correct display]

In IE6, IE7, and IE8 in Quirks or IE7 Standards modes the `input` field is displayed, but not the calendar icon.

[image: Incorrect display]

I think I've narrowed it down to a problem rendering the span that contains the icon.  The HTML for this span is:

```
<span class="t-icon t-icon-calendar" title="Open the calendar">Open the calendar</span>
```

and the CSS applied to the `span` is:

[image: css rules]

The problem seems to be that the `span` is being rendered with width and height of 0px, regardless of what's specified in the CSS.  Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

I've tried setting `font-size` and `line-height` to `12px`, but it didn't help.

**Answer Update**

It turns out that the styling on the span wasn't the problem at all.  I had some styling on the input element (float: left) which caused the span containing the image to end up behind the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the styling on the span wasn't the problem at all.  I had some styling on the input element (float: left) which caused the span containing the image to end up behind the input.

I've added this as an update to the question also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/calendar-icon-not-showing-in-ie-lt-8.aspx) to the forum thread opened on the same matter. I believe the questions is already answered.